# Google App Engine-Deployment Error

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I am trying to deploy a simple sample website on Google App Engine . I am using Ubuntu 12.10.

However,I am having a problem when I try to upload using the appcfg.py file. I am getting the following error

```
ERROR appcfg.py:2152 An error occurred processing file '':<urlopen error [Errno 110]      Connection timed out>. Aborting.
```

Upon Googling this and sever other stackoverflow posts, the suggested solution was that urllib is not opening the requested url probably due to a proxy server which is not allowing the requested connection. So they had asked me to give the correct proxy settings (like using export http_proxy ,https_proxy.)

But the problem is that I am not behind any proxy server, I am directly connecting to the internet via my ethernet connection. I checked all the environment variables http_proxy and https_proxy in ~/.bashrc ,/etc/environment, /etc/bash.bashrc to check for incorrect proxy settings ,but all those variables are not set to anything (and they neednt be set to anything since I am not behind any proxy server)

I am still getting the error , can anyone please help me out on this ? Why am I not able to upload my sample site using appcfg.py?

Comment: What is the exact command you are running?

Comment: if my required files(app.yaml and my python file) are in the folder samplewebsite which by itself is in the desktop.If i am in my desktop and the google_appengine folder is in the desktop 

    "google_appengine/appcfg.py update samplewebsite/"

Comment: Can you paste some more info about your system e.g. a longer transcript of your session with the command prompt plus some useful routing info perhaps a traceroute to appengine.com from your client could be useful to see where the connection is lost.